# Is there any way to modify the titles of opened PDFs displayed on the tabs?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, pdf

I used to work on Chrome but I am considering to switch to Safari entirely due to the horrible battery efficiency of Chrome. I noticed when opening PDF files, the titles of tabs all appeared as links which unfortunately means I can't see any difference between them:

[image]

Here you can see 1 website and 4 PDFs opened from it with these horrible url titles that make it difficult to know which is which.

Here's how it looks on Chrome:

[image]

Safari browser on Macbook Pro 2017

Comment: Personally, I'd throw them out to Preview rather than wade through PDFs in any browser. Right click [sometimes fiddly but clicking in the middle of a word is usually a sure bet] Open with Preview. Once finished you can just close. It won't save or prompt to Save unless you want to, it will just silently vanish.

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't know you could do that! Although for the amount of PDFs I have opened at the same time, viewing them in a browser helps a lot with compactness and saves time. Anyway, thank you for the tip, I'll be using that feature for sure